# Javascript on ipad loads slow

Tags: javascript, ipad, html, latency

I have a basic html site (html5 , JavaScript, jQuery) that I have running on an iPpad2. I do basic testing with a Google Chrome, just to test layout images and copy etc. My real test however needs to be on an actual iPad.

On the iPad, my code seems to have a 2-4 second delay as compared to Chrome which loads instantly. I have been unable to find the bottleneck. I added alerts at various points in the code, but all the alerts appear immediately, one after the other and it seems the delay occurs after the last alert which is at the last line of code.

The alerts may be misleading as maybe the code is cached before its executed? Is there something I should look for or avoid in my code in order to speed things up on the iPad?

Comment: What mode of feedback are you looking for? In other words, what is the code supposed to do that you are seeing a delay in? For example, are you looking for a change to the HTML content?

Comment: We've been having this issue as well on a first gen iPad, specifically with animations. I think the older ones just have a hard time processing a bunch of javascript (they are much slower than most desktops+laptops). However, we picked up an iPad 3 today and everything ran extremely well.

Comment: @wescam. Yes I'm looking to see HTML content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An iPad is considerably slower than a desktop running Google Chrome would be. It's expected to take a bit longer to do things.

If it was 10-20 seconds, I'd say check your code, but 2-4 seconds isn't unreasonable for a page load.

Comment: I'm starting to agree with you...I also tried adding a simple div containing just one image first in the index.html to see if it would appear faster and STILL the 3 second delay....

Answer (score 8):

If you do not cache your selector results - mobile devices are susceptible to poor performance

what I mean is if you do this:

```
$("#someId").css(some, stuff);
$("#someId").css(other, stuffs);
$("#someId").attr(even, more);
```

compared to

```
var ourElement = $("#someId");
ourElement.css(some, stuff);
ourElement.css(other, stuffs);
ourElement.attr(even, more);
```

now if you are doing the prior "in the real world" - in loops, etc.. - it can amount to a huge performance detriment to mobile devices

good luck

Comment: OP might also try using jQuery mobile as opposed to full blown jQuery if they have a specific mobile site.

Comment: jQuery Mobile relies on jQuery, so it wouldn't have a smaller footprint.

Comment: Not a smaller footprint, no.  But it does have some mobile-specific things that take into consideration the lower available resources on mobile devices.

Comment: tried adding the jquery mobile js and It didn't make a difference.

Comment: as Pheonix mentioned, jquery mobile simply provides easier access to mobile device specific events and such (like iOS gestures, etc.. ). The core of your issue likely lies in not caching your selector values that are used repeatedly and not optimizing your selectors to be as specific as possible